# Скрипт для распределения заказов в зависимости от приоритета

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Делаю таблицу для распределения заказов в зависимости от приоритета. Типография, есть несколько станков, на каждом станке выполняется определенный процесс. К каждому станку присвоен номер (1,2,3...7). К каждой операции так же присвоен свой номер.

[ссылка на таблицу](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mHMZ3mBbNDzW_NQeL8CJqlkvSqAPdsVOZJ7AucntD7w/edit?usp=sharing)

"Флексо печать, Ротационная высечка, Холодное тиснение, Лакирование" = №5.Так как делается на одном станке.
"Офсетная печать, Полуротационная высечка, Холодное тиснение, Лакирование"  = №10, так же делается на одном станке.
Конгревое тиснение №20, Горячее тиснение №21, Высечка плоская №22, так же делается на одном станке.
 Но №5 и №10 не прерываемые (то есть к примеру от офсетной печати до лакирования процесс не прерывается), а №20,21,22 можно закончив один процесс отложить заказ и пустить в работу более приоритетный заказ.
Шелкография №30, Инспекция №40, Перемотка №50, Инспекция перемотка №60 (№30-60 это разные станки).

Распределение заказов должно происходить по факту поступления, то есть заказы 
2-0153-10-С
1-0154-5
3-0155-10-С
3-0155-10
2-0153-10
2-0153-20 и т.д. (Лист-База,ячейки "V7:V22")
Не должны сразу распределятся по временной шкале, а распределение должно быть по факту завершения предыдущей операции. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужен код который будет распределять заказы по временной шкале (как показано на картинке) закрашивая столько ячеек, сколько часов будет выполняться заказ. Далее когда при завершеннии операции добавляет следующий заказ, смотря в первую очередь на приоритет заказа.

Если есть предложения как еще можно реализовать этот проект, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: № заказа "2-0153-10-С", где 2- это приоритет заказа, 0153 - номер заказа, 10 - № операции для определения станка, С - заказы которые можно пустить одновременно на Офсетную печать (макс. 3)

Comment: Картинка с шкалой взята с видео https://youtu.be/YIidZomp1p4?si=Zn8uJXeM2RUDJuXd&t=790